# Suppressing Group Data In Crystal Reports (Top 50 in Group 3)

Tags: crystal-reports

Ok, so I have been digging through these forums and am failing to find what I am looking for.

I have a report that shows our product sales that is grouped by Month and then Product Type. There are actually 3 groupings. Group 1 is my date (which is a formula to get the date to list properly). Group 2 is our product category (data.ITEM_USER_DEF_CODE). Finally, Group 3 is the item itself (data.ITEM_NO). Details lists all of the invoices every item had for it and is suppressed.

I am trying to only show the top 50 items (group 3) for each Product Type (group 2) under each month (group 1). That way my sales team can look at each month and see which items were hot under each of the product categories.

I have tried going to the section expert and going to Group 3 header and doing a formula ( = recordnumber > 50) and that doesn't work. I have also tried (groupnumber > 50) and had no luck either.

I am lost on this and haven't been able to find an example similar to this anywhere. Anybody have any suggestions on how I can pull this off?

Comment: I would try to count the rows in your group using a running total, then suppress row > 50.

Comment: post it as answer and accept it so that others can use

Answer (score 1):

I did exactly what Justin said. I threw a count on the rows in the group via running total and then suppressed row > 50. Thanks a bunch for the help Justin! It was greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would try to count the rows in your group using a running total, then suppress row > 50.